# D3 taking an array of two objects and reading it into a D3 shape

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, svg

I am new to D3 and have a basic question. When calling a service, I receive an array of objects. When I do console.log(typeof(...)) it shows an array.

The array contains two objects. For example, if there were two fields. It would use.

```
City  Airport

Chicago 80
New York 42
```

I am creating a dot plot, but right now, I just want to access data without getting errors.

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
 .data( ????)
 .attr('cx', function(d){ d.City }
```

I looked into d3.json or d3.nest, but am frankly lost right now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How is the data formatted? You basically just put your array of data into the data function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data array looks something like this:

```
var dataArray = [{
  "City": "Chicago",
  "Airport": 80
},
{...}
]
```

you should be able to bind this data through its name easily, as with:

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
 .data(dataArray)          # or whatever name you have
 .attr('cx', function(d){ 
   return d.City;          # note that you need to use return
 }
```

If you can provide a bit more info about your dataset, it would be helpful.

Comment: I hardcoded the javascript object and this worked. Unfortunately, I think it's potentially an Angular problem as I am just not able to get this into proper form. Thanks!

Comment: Finally got the angular to work and then used your technique. Thank you!